# Can you build your own MSTEST DataSource

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, mstest, data-driven-tests

I have been looking for a way to build my own DataSource for data driven unit tests in MSTEST. I have not found any documentation how to do this or any base class or interface that I need to implement. Any ideas?

I'm looking at building something similar to FITNesse but using Team Foundation Server for my backing store.

Answer (score 3):

This is the response i got from Mathew Aniyan at Microsoft

> Unfortunately the data source mechanism is not extensible.
>   I will add a feature request to make this extensible. This will *not* make it into VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, with MsTest v2, a custom data source for a data driven test method is something that is very easy to handle.
See the answer for https://stackoverflow.com/a/66312973/8194898
As well, a working demo code can be tried from
https://github.com/matei-tm/howto-demos/tree/main/MstestCustomDataSource