# MSTest data driven Test set DisplayName for Rows from DataSource

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mstest, xmldatasource, data-driven-tests, test-reporting

How can I set the DisplayName of a Data Row in data driven tests, where the data source is a XML and the provider is Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<environments>
    <environment><name>IE</name></environment>
    <environment><name>Chrome</name></environment>
</environments>
```

App Config:

```
<!-- CONNECTION STRINGS SETTINGS -->
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IE_Chrome" connectionString="IE_Chrome.xml" providerName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML"/>
</connectionStrings>
<!-- PARAMETERIZING TEST SETTINGS -->
<microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
    <dataSources>
        <add name="IE_Chrome" connectionString="IE_Chrome" dataTableName="environment" dataAccessMethod="Sequential"/>
    </dataSources>
</microsoft.visualstudio.testtools>
```

The Output:

[image]

I'd like to display the Environment Name instead of "Data Row 0".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible with a custom data source attribute. An example can be:

```cs
public class XmlCustomDataSourceAttribute : Attribute, ITestDataSource
{
    public IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        foreach (var environment in YourStaticXmlParser.GetEnvironments())
        {
            yield return new object[] { environment.Name };
        }
    }

    public string GetDisplayName(MethodInfo methodInfo, object[] data)
    {
        if (data != null)
        { 
            return string.Format("Target Environmment- {0} ({1})", methodInfo.Name, data[0]); 
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and the test method should look like:

```cs
        [DataTestMethod]
        [XmlCustomDataSource]
        public void Should_Blur(string environmentName)
        {
            var actualEnvironment = SomeMethodToGetActualEnvironment();
            Assert.AreEqual(environmentName, actualEnvironment);
        }
```

Finally your test detail will be:
[image]

Comment: A complete demo solution can be found here: https://github.com/matei-tm/howto-demos/tree/main/MstestCustomDataSource