# MsTest, 'Data Driven Test' output change from Data Row 0, Data Row 1 to meaningfull message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mstest, data-driven-tests

I'm working on Visual Studio 2015.
Output of the [Data Driven Test](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx) looks something like this this

```
Failed TestCaseName(Data Row 0)
Failed TestCaseName(Data Row 1)
Failed TestCaseName(Data Row 3)
Passed TestCaseName(Data Row 4)
```

Is there a way to display a meaningfull message instead of `Data Row n`. Something like

```
Failed TestCaseName(with SQL Server data source)
Failed TestCaseName(with Oracle data source)
Failed TestCaseName(with MYSql data source)
```

or

```
Failed TestCaseName_SQLServer(Data Row 0)
Failed TestCaseName_Oracle(Data Row 1)
Failed TestCaseName_MySql(Data Row 2)
```

I have tried with.

```
TestContext.Properties["TestName"] = "TestCaseName_SQLServer"; 
TestContext.Properties["FullyQualifiedTestClassName"] = "TestCaseName_SQLServer";
```

But no luck. [This is the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23618483/instead-of-data-row-0-data-row-1-etc-output-a-custom-name) but not answered.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a meaningfull message, you must use a custom data source attribute. See the answer posted for https://stackoverflow.com/a/66312973/8194898
As well, a working, demo code source is posted on github https://github.com/matei-tm/howto-demos/tree/main/MstestCustomDataSource
The demo presents a mock Pass and Fail for a custom data source
[image]